# VS 2017 .Net Core project templates

Tags: .net-core

I am following an article:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-7-project-with-asp-net-core-apis-gym-project/

I am trying to create the 5 project solution (Note: the author does not explain how he created the solution/projects). 1 project is a .Net Core / ASP.NET Core Web Application. The other 4 are like 'class library' projects but when I try to create them I can't seem to find the correct project template for. These 4 projects have a properties and references folder (also 1 has an app.config file).

[image]

I tried the .Net Core/Class Library(.Net Core) template, however, it only creates a Class and Dependencies folder in the project.

[image]

[image]

What .net core template do I use?

Answer (score 0):

You have the right template. It is a "Class Library (.NET Core)". The "Properties" can be added as a new folder (The icon is just used on a folder with that name). The app.config and Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs have types when add new item (see image). And the references section is only added when the project has dependencies (right click Dependencies -> Add References..).

[image: New item file types for app.config and assembly info]

Comment: Ok..I thought these would all be part of the selection of a template. Anyway, I did everything except the References section. In the Author's project (the screen shot at the top) there is no Dependencies section. I don't want it, just a References section. So why was 1 created for me when selecting the "Class Library (.NET Core)" template?  I'm trying to make it look just like the Author's. Also, there is no item to add for just a References section (note it has that icon to the left of it that I don't see anywhere as a choice) so I do not see how to add it.

Comment: Not entirely sure what that project is doing or why, but it looks like the class libraries are .net framework not .net core.

Comment: Yeah..weird. However if you look at the Author's link, you see that it is what he used. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/angular-7-project-with-asp-net-core-apis-gym-project/